# Fastapi websockets.exceptions.PayloadTooBig: payload length exceeds size limit

Tags: fastapi

I have created a backend server and we are sending data from the frontend to the backend by using sockets. Now we have to share some images that are encoded into base64.

When we are doing that we are getting below error.

```bash
websockets.exceptions.PayloadTooBig: payload length exceeds size limit
```

Below connection manager class.

```py
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: List[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_text(message)
    
    async def send_json(self, json, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.send_json(json)

    async def broadcast(self, message: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(message)

manager = ConnectionManager()
```

```py
await manager.connect(websocket)
json.loads(await websocket.receive_text())
```

Comment: You can set the `max_size` parameter when setting up to the websocket: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/api.html#module-websockets.server or when connecting with a client: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/api.html#module-websockets.client

Comment: @MatsLindh, I could not able to find out where to pass the `max_size` parameter. I try with `await websockets.client.connect()` and getting error `AttributeError: 'Address' object has no attribute 'connect'`.

Comment: @MatsLindh, The above document does not belong to FastAPI.

Comment: The [Uvicorn docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/#command-line-options) mention a `--ws-max-size` argument for the max message size in bytes (default: 16777216, or 16 MiB). Try setting this to a higher number? `uvicorn [module].app --ws-max-size=[some very large number]`